# Find the value of ${p\over r}+{r\over p}$ given certain conditions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $a,b,c$ are in A.P ; $p,q,r$ are in H.P. And $ap,bq,cr $ are in G.P. Then what is the value of ${p\over r} + {r\over p}\ \ ?$
>
> $i)$ ${a\over c}-{c\over a}$ $\ \ ii)$ ${a\over c}+{c\over a}$ $\ \ iii)$ ${b\over q}-{a\over p}$  $\ \ iv)$ ${b\over q}+{a\over p}$

$a,b,c$ are in A.P. $$b=a+d\\c=a+2d.$$
$p,q,r$ are in H.P. $$p={1\over x}\\q={1\over {x+k}}\\r={1\over {x+2k}}.$$
$ap,bq,cr$ are in G.P. $$bq=ap\cdot m\\cr=ap\cdot m^2$$
Usinfg the third , $${p\over r}+{r\over p}=\\{c\over am^2}+{am^2\over c}$$
Now $?$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=b-d,c=b+d$

and $p=\dfrac1{x-D}, q=\dfrac1x, r=\dfrac1{x+D}$

$ap\cdot cr=(bq)^2\implies\dfrac{b^2}{x^2}=\dfrac{b-d}{x-D}\dfrac{b+d}{x+D}=\dfrac{b^2-d^2}{x^2-D^2}=\dfrac{d^2}{D^2}=k$(say)

$\implies b^2=kx^2,d^2=kD^2$

$\dfrac rp+\dfrac pr=\dfrac{x-D}{x+D}+\dfrac{x+D}{x-D}=\dfrac{2(x^2+D^2)}{x^2-D^2}$

$\dfrac ac+\dfrac ca=\dfrac{b-d}{b+d}+\dfrac{b+d}{b-d}=\dfrac{2(b^2+d^2)}{b^2-d^2}=\dfrac{2(kx^2+kD^2)}{kx^2-kD^2}=?$

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry is easier to see if you keep $b$ and $y=1/q$, rather than $a$ and $x=1/p$.
$$\frac{b-d}{y-k},\frac by,\frac{b+d}{y+k}\text{ are in GP}\\
(b^2-d^2)y^2=b^2(y^2-k^2)\\ \frac db=\pm \frac ky$$
You have some manipulation to go.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$a+c=2b$$
$$\frac 1p+\frac 1r=\frac 2q\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{p+r}{pr}=\frac 2q\quad\Rightarrow\quad p+r=\frac{2pr}{q}$$
$$apcr=(bq)^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{pr}{q^2}=\frac{b^2}{ac}$$

we have
$$\begin{align}\frac pr+\frac rp&=\frac{(p+r)^2-2pr}{pr}\\\\&=\frac{\left(\frac{2pr}{q}\right)^2-2pr}{pr}\\\\&=\frac{4pr}{q^2}-2\\\\&=4\cdot\frac{b^2}{ac}-2\\\\&=\frac{(a+c)^2}{ac}-2\\\\&=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}\\\\&=\frac ac+\frac ca\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's eliminate $d, k, m$:
\begin{align}
c - b &= b - a \tag 1\\
\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{q} &= \frac{1}{q} - \frac{1}{p} \tag 2 \\
\frac{cr}{bq} &= \frac{bq}{ap} \tag 3
\end{align}
We're aiming for $\frac{p}{r} + \frac{r}{p} = \frac{p^2 + r^2}{rp}$. That sort of looks like $(2)$. Let's try manipulating $(2)$ a bit:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{r} = \frac{2}{q} 
&\implies r + p = \frac{2pr}{q} \\
&\implies p^2 + 2pr + r^2 = \frac{4p^2r^2}{q^2} \\
&\implies p^2 + r^2 = \frac{4p^2r^2}{q^2} - 2pr \\
&\implies \frac{p^2 + r^2}{rp} = \frac{4pr}{q^2} - 2 \tag 4
\end{align*}
We've got what we wanted! Except there's that tricky $pr/q^2$ on the RHS. But what if we manipulate $(3)$:
$$
acpr = b^2q^2 \implies \frac{pr}{q^2} = \frac{b^2}{ac}
$$
Getting closer! Now $(4)$ becomes:
$$
\frac{p^2 + r^2}{rp} = \frac{4b^2}{ac} - 2 \tag 5
$$
Now we just need to eliminate $b^2$. That's where $(1)$ comes into play:
$$
a + c = 2b \implies b = \frac{a + c}{2} \implies b^2 = \frac{a^2 + 2ac + c^2}{4}
$$
Substitute that into $(5)$ and we're home free:
\begin{align*}
\frac{p^2 + r^2}{rp}
&= \frac{4(\frac{a^2 + 2ac + c^2}{4})}{ac} - 2 \\
&= \frac{(a^2 + 2ac + c^2) - 2(ac)}{ac} \\
&= \frac{a^2 + c^2}{ac}
\end{align*}
Hence, we conclude that:
$$
\boxed{\frac{p}{r} + \frac{r}{p} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{c}{a}}
$$